# Can I use allocator specified for some type to allocate objects of another type in C++?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

Some container `A` has a template parameter `Alloc` (that is a template too) representing an allocator type. `A` specifies `Alloc` for the type `A::Node`.

```
template <template <T> Alloc>
class A {
    struct Node {
    };

    Alloc<Node> allocator_; // the allocator object
};
```

Please excuse me for possibly wrong C++ code above.

So, `allocator_.allocate(1)` will allocate `sizeof(A::Node)` bytes. But during operation, container `A` needs a memory for some object of other than A::Node type, say a temporary string (of `char`s).

From technical point of view, I could use existing allocator in such a dirty way:

```
 size_t string_len = 500;
 // how much objects spanned in memory is enough to fit our string?
 size_t equal_size = (string_len / sizeof(Node)) + 1;

 auto mem = allocator_.allocate(equal_size);
 char *p = (char*)mem; // reinterpret cast
 // ... use p to store the string ... memcpy(p, str_src, str_len); //

 // Now p is not needed, so return memory to allocator: 
 allocator_.deallocate(mem, equal_size);
```

Is there a less dirty approach, considering I need no more than 1 allocator and I wish to put all the memory management to it?

All this comes from those needs:

- to have a single allocator that could be killed to free all (possibly leaked) memory that A is allocated for any its purposes during operation
- to have not more than 1 allocator (including the default ::new, ::delete)

Comment: `to have a single allocator that could be killed to free all (possibly leaked) memory that A is allocated ` That's quite a fancy allocator. How would you propose to implement it?

Comment: @user2079303 any kind of allocator is holding a pages of memory returned by operating system. It is enough to return that pages back to OS and you've done. You don't have to dive into allocator details (how it manages its lists (free/allocated) of little chunks placed in that pages).

Comment: OK, I think I get the idea. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::allocator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) has a member type `rebind` for exactly that purpose:

```
std::allocator<Node> alloc;

std::allocator<Node>::rebind<char>::other char_alloc;

char * mem = char_alloc.allocate(string_len);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an allocator's [`rebind`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/allocator/rebind/) for this. From [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5fk3e8ek.aspx):

> A structure that enables an allocator for objects of one type to allocate storage for objects of another type.

it is built exactly for your case - taking an allocator type oriented to one type, and building the corresponding one oriented to some other type.

In your case, it might look like

```
typename Alloc<T>::rebind<Node>::other allocator_;
```

Comment: If we're referring to `std::allocator`, `rebind` is defined and is the way to go; but if the OP is talking about Allocators in general, `rebind` is optional.

Comment: @black I suppose if it's something that doesn't support `rebind`, then it should be a template template parameter. But any allocator I've seen (including non-STL ones) supported `rebind`.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use [`Alloc::rebind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator) member template to get an allocator for that another object.

However, that does mean that you do have 2 allocators. The advantage of `rebind` is to allow the user of your template to specify the allocator type only for a single allocated type.

Also note that `rebind` is optional, so if you must support such allocators, you'll need to pass the other allocator as an argument, but you can still use the rebound allocator as a default value.